# I want to convert the below array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert the below array:

```
["A:100","B:234","C:124","D:634","E:543","F:657"];
```

Into:

```
["100:234:124:634:543:657"];
```

How to do this?

Comment: so what have you tried ? And how you want to convert it?

Comment: I tried this

var valArray = [];
                  var data = ["A:100","B:234","C:124","D:634","E:543","F:657"];
                  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                   {
                    var splitAttr = data[i].split(":");
                    valArray.push(splitAttr[1] + ':');
                   }
                  alert(valArray);

but the result was

100:,234:,124:,634:,543:,657:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So not sure why you would want that particular output since it would just be a single item in an array but this should work:

```js
var testArray = ["A:100","B:234","C:124","D:634","E:543","F:657"];

var resultArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < testArray.length; ++i) {
  resultArray.push(testArray[i].split(':')[1]);
}

var strValue = resultArray.join(':');
console.log(strValue);

resultArray = [strValue];
console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate the array, return the number on the right and join it with `':'`.

```js
var data = ["A:100","B:234","C:124","D:634","E:543","F:657"],
    result = [data.map(function (a) {
        return a.match(/\d*$/);
    }).join(':')];

console.log(result);
```

Or a bit shorter

```js
var data = ["A:100","B:234","C:124","D:634","E:543","F:657"],
    result = [data.map(RegExp.prototype.exec.bind(/\d*$/)).join(':')];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
var arr=["A:100","B:234","C:124","D:634","E:543","F:657"];
var str='';
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  str+=arr[i].split(":")[1]+":";
   }
 console.log(str.substring(0, str.length - 1));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just keep the number behind ":" and join new elements with ":"

```js
var data = ["A:100","B:234","C:124","D:634","E:543","F:657"];
var results = [data.map(x => x.split(":")[1]).join(":")];
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You join it with what you want `:`, split it by what you don't won't `/\D\:/` (non digit followed by `:`), and then join it using an empty string `''`:

```js
var arr = ["A:100","B:234","C:124","D:634","E:543","F:657"];

var result = [arr.join(':').split(/\D\:/).join('')];

console.log(result);
```